# How to build rs fie in AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, renderscript

I am using AndroidStudio. I want to develop with RenderScript, when I create a file hello.rs and build the project，then I try to use ScriptC_hello in java file,but the compiler cannot
find ScriptC_hello class，I think ScriptC_hello.class did not create，but how to create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your .rs file is in the app/src/main/rs directory in your project.  Unlike Eclipse based projects, all your .rs files need to reside here by default rather than alongside the Java files from the same package.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio expects .rs files to be in app/src/main/rs, but you can also override the renderscript source directory in build.gradle.

```
// build.gradle    

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        }
    }
}
```